# Using Generic Types with Entity Framework & ADO.NET models

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to use generic methods with Entity Frameworks?

For instance, I have the tables: `TblPlan` and `TblTier`. Can I pass these in a generic method and find the type? Each table have slightly different values and I want to compare the values differently for each. I tried:

```
public static Dictionary<T, List<T>> checkDuplicates<T>(T something)
   {
      try
      {
         //TblCommissionPlan plan = (TblCommissionPlan)something;
         //var type = typeof(something);
      }
   }
```

These didn't work...any ideas?

Comment: when you mean check different values, what values are you trying to check?

Comment: For instance if I have `Plan.nm == Plan2.nm`

Comment: So you want to check the Properties of the plan that EF generates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a purpose of generic methods. If you write a method which has signature:

```
public Dictionary<T, List<T>> CheckDuplicates<T>(T something)
```

you are defining "a shared logic". It means that the same logic must work for every `T` passed to the method. If it doesn't you must constraint the `T` by using some kind of constraint:

```
public Dictionary<T, List<T>> CheckDuplicates<T>(T something) where T : ISomeInterface
```

Now you know that every `T` passed to the method must implement `ISomeInterface` and you can use in your method any property or method declared on that interface.

Content of the method is not supposed to be different for different type of `T` but logic can because you can call `T`s methods and properties which can have different implementation. If it is not enough you can pass another parameter - generic delegate or some another generic class based on `T` which will add some additional logic for you.

In you scenario you want to compare each passed class differently => comparison cannot be part of your method but it must either be part of your entities or you must pass additional class / method which will do the comparison for the method.

For implementing comparison directly in your classes you can implement `IComparable<T>` interface and declare your method as:

```
public Dictionary<T, List<T>> CheckDuplicates<T>(T something) where T : IComparable<T>
```

For implementing comparison outside of your classes you can simply use `Func<T, T, int>` or implementation of `IComparer<T>`:

```
public Dictionary<T, List<T>> CheckDuplicates<T>(T something, IComparer<T> comparer)
```

In either case I'm not sure how does this relate to entity framework because signature of your method has nothing to do with EF.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class I use to show Properties of a single Entity that is Generated by EF.

You can build on this to compare two different Entities, it should be a good starting point.

```
namespace Solutions.Data.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Linq;

    public static class EntityExtensions
    {
        #region Fields

        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]> PropertyInfoCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]>();

        #endregion

        #region Extension Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// This method will find all the Properties of Entity and display them in formatted way.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Entity Type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="value">Entity value</param>
        /// <returns>Formatted string of the Entity Properties</returns>
        public static string PropertiesToString<T>(this T value) where T : IObjectWithChangeTracker
        {
            var type = typeof(T).FullName;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(type)) return String.Empty;

            CachePropertyInfo<T>(type);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in PropertyInfoCache[type])
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(value, null)));
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use reflection to find all propertied if key is not found in list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Entity Type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="type">property fullname</param>
        private static void CachePropertyInfo<T>(string type)
        {
            if (!PropertyInfoCache.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                // Get all public properties of T type where T inherits interface IObjectWithChangeTracker
                var properties =
                    typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.Name != "ChangeTracker");
                PropertyInfoCache[type] = properties.ToArray();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```